# NodeJS Error "npm install" of a GitHub downloaded Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-install

I have downloaded i NodeJS Project from Github. If i try to run it by typing in : **npm install** i get a list of errors. How can i fix this? Do i have to download modules or a specific version of Node?`

Error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
```

Complete Error: https://codeshare.io/JbBmxR

Package.json File:

```
{
"name": "360-panorama-tour-viewer-and-editor",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "backend/server.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "npm-run-all --parallel webpack-start nodemon",
"nodemon": "nodemon server.js",
"debug": "nodemon --inspect server.js",
"webpack-start": "webpack --mode development --watch -- 
 progress",
"webpack-build": "webpack --mode production",
"docker-build": "docker build -t <NAME>/panorama360 .",
"docker-run": "docker run -d --rm --name panorama360 -p 
 8080:3000 
<NAME>/panorama360"
 },
"author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.9.4",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
"bowser": "^2.9.0",
"core-js": "^3.6.4",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"fs-extra": "^9.0.0",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"jsx-render": "^1.1.1",
"jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
"leaflet": "^1.8.0",
"leaflet-rotatedmarker": "^0.2.0",
"marzipano": "^0.9.1",
"mongoose": "^4.13.21",
"multer": "^1.4.2",
"nedb-for-mongoose": "^3.0.1",
"nedb-mongoose-driver": "^2.0.2",
"nodemon": "^2.0.2",
"npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
"screenfull": "^5.0.2",
"serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
"sharp": "^0.25.2",
"swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
"webpack": "^5.72.1",
"webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
}
}
```

Comment: There must be more to the error code than the one you’ve posted. There should probably be a message printed to your console or terminal that the error message is stored in a log file. What does the log file say?

Comment: This is the Error Message i get after npm install: https://codeshare.io/JbBmxR

Comment: Please include the error in the question. It does seem to mention the issue.

Comment: The error log tells you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @Terry i'm, very new to Node Js and React, could you help me with the steps to fix the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to error logs, it says:

```
find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
```